# Scala abstract class function call

Tags: scala

I am new to scala and I apologize in advance if the question is stupid. I am browsing through this scala code and I am confused how the following code works

```
abstract class ClusterSimulatorDesc(val runTime: Double) {
  def newSimulator(constantThinkTim: Double,
               perTaskThinkTime: Double,
               blackListPercent: Double,
               schedulerWorkloadsToSweepOver: Map[String, Seq[String]],
               workloadToSchedulerMap: Map[String, Seq[String]],
               cellStateDesc: CellStateDesc,
               workloads: Seq[Workload],
               prefillWorkloads: Seq[Workload],
               logging: Boolean = false): ClusterSimulator
}

class ClusterSimulator(val cellState: CellState,
                   val schedulers: Map[String, Scheduler],
                   val workloadToSchedulerMap: Map[String, Seq[String]],
                   val workloads: Seq[Workload],
                   prefillWorkloads: Seq[Workload],
                   logging: Boolean = false,
                   monitorUtilization: Boolean = true,
                   monitoringPeriod: Double = 1.0)
                  extends Simulator(logging) {
```

Now if i have a function call like:-

```
simulatorDesc: ClusterSimulatorDesc
val simulator =
              simulatorDesc.newSimulator(constantThinkTime,
                                         perTaskThinkTime,
                                         blackListPercent,
                                         schedulerWorkloadsToSweepOver,
                                         schedulerWorkloadMap,
                                         workloadDesc.cellStateDesc,
                                         workloads,
                                         prefillWorkloads,
                                         logging)
```

Now the question I have is, what does "ClusterSimulator" at the end of the abstract class declaration does?
And, how does the calling of "newSimulator" function happen, considering that its declared in an abstract class?

Comment: You can read up on Inheritance (OOP concept). Here is a brief info: http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/125. More detailed: http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/composition-and-inheritance.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def newSimulator(....): ClusterSimulator
```

The method `newSimulator()`, when invoked, returns an instance of `ClusterSimulator`.

```
simulatorDesc: ClusterSimulatorDesc
```

`ClusterSimulatorDesc` can't be instantiated because it is abstract, but a class that extends `ClusterSimulatorDesc` can be instantiated and an instance of **that** class is **also** an instance of `ClusterSimulatorDesc` and can invoke its methods.